# left join to a left join

Tags: sql, join

The following code works fine:

```
SELECT *    -- * only for clarity
FROM
   (    SELECT      dbo.Contracts.buyerID AS PreviousContractPartyIDs 
        FROM        dbo.Contracts 
        WHERE       dbo.Contracts.sellerID = @UserID 
        GROUP BY    dbo.Contracts.buyerID 

        UNION

        SELECT      dbo.Contracts.sellerID 
        FROM        dbo.Contracts 
        WHERE       dbo.Contracts.BuyerID = @UserID 
        GROUP BY    dbo.Contracts.sellerID 
   ) AS ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith

LEFT JOIN 

  ( SELECT  dbo.Members.ID, 
            dbo.Members.Name, 
            dbo.Members.Description 
    FROM    dbo.Members 
  ) AS MemberDetails 

ON ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.PreviousContractPartyIDs = MemberDetails.ID
```

The top selects all users the Member has traded with and the bottom select adds detail about each of them. However the member may have added notes about each user in tbl.Notes but I can't figure out the synatx/structure to add another join essentially as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT MemberID, NoteAboutMemberID, Note, UTC from dbo.Notes ) AS NoteDetails     

ON ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.PreviousContractPartyIDs = NoteDetails.NoteAboutMemberID
```

Comment: Have you tried this additional join yet?  Note that you could use `SELECT DISTINCT` in your union query and remove the `GROUP BY`, since you are not actually selecting any aggregates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important fact to consider,

1. Is your subquery ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith is distinct in the ID "PreviousContractPartyIDs" ?

then the below code would do, since you use the UNION syntax subquery would already be distinct you can avoid the group by since there is no aggregation.
Finally left join both sub-queries.

```
SELECT *   
FROM
   (    SELECT      dbo.Contracts.buyerID AS PreviousContractPartyIDs 
        FROM        dbo.Contracts 
        WHERE       dbo.Contracts.sellerID = @UserID 


        UNION

        SELECT      dbo.Contracts.sellerID 
        FROM        dbo.Contracts 
        WHERE       dbo.Contracts.BuyerID = @UserID 

   ) AS ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith

LEFT JOIN 

  ( SELECT DISTINCT  dbo.Members.ID, 
            dbo.Members.Name, 
            dbo.Members.Description 
    FROM    dbo.Members 
  ) AS MemberDetails 

ON ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.PreviousContractPartyIDs = MemberDetails.ID

LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT DISTINCT MemberID, NoteAboutMemberID, Note, UTC from dbo.Notes ) AS NoteDetails     

ON ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.PreviousContractPartyIDs = NoteDetails.NoteAboutMemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need below

```
    SELECT ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.*,
            MemberDetails.*,
               NoteDetails.*
    FROM
       (    SELECT      distinct dbo.Contracts.buyerID AS PreviousContractPartyIDs 
            FROM        dbo.Contracts 
            WHERE       dbo.Contracts.sellerID = @UserID 


            UNION

            SELECT      distinct dbo.Contracts.sellerID 
            FROM        dbo.Contracts 
            WHERE       dbo.Contracts.BuyerID = @UserID 

       ) AS ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith

    LEFT JOIN 

      ( SELECT  dbo.Members.ID, 
                dbo.Members.Name, 
                dbo.Members.Description 
        FROM    dbo.Members 
      ) AS MemberDetails 

    ON ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.PreviousContractPartyIDs = MemberDetails.ID
 LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT MemberID, NoteAboutMemberID, Note, UTC from dbo.Notes ) AS NoteDetails     

ON ListOfAllMembersPreviouslyTradedWith.PreviousContractPartyIDs = NoteDetails.MemberID AND MemberDetails.ID = NoteDetails.NoteAboutMemberID
```